# C# Why cannot I write custom IEnumerator for my class

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a simple class that represents a Vertex in a graph that is most likely a tree. Thus, this class looks like this:

```
class Vertex {
  public Vertex parent;
  public List<Vertex> children;
}
```

In unlikely case of loops, I can just link to same vertex as child multiple times.

Now, I made an enumerator that would give every vertex in the graph. So that you can do

```
foreach (Vertex item in rootVertex)
```

and get every vertex in the graph. For this, I had to make my class IEnumerable{Vertex} and write GetEnumerator method that yields all Vertexes recursively.

Now, for purposes of drawing the graph, I would like  to also have another enumerator in the same class that would return every edge in the graph. So i could do something like

```
foreach (Point[] item in rootVertex.GetEdges())
```

And get all edges. For this purpose, to avoid confusion, I removed IEnumerable from my class and implemented two methods like this

```
public IEnumerator<Vertex> GetVertexes() { ...code... }
public IEnumerator<Point[]> GetEdges() { ...code... }
```

However, when I try to do

```
foreach (Point[] item in rootVertex.GetEdges())
```

It spits error - foreach cannot enumerate over rootVertex because Vertex class does not containin GetEnumerator method.

I tried googling but didnt find wether or not I can or cannot make multiple enumerators on the same class.

Comment: Can you post the entire `Vertex` class including `GetVertexes` / `GetEdges`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and obvious, you should have `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerator` as return result:

```
public IEnumerable<Point[]> GetEdges() { ...code... }
```

Comment: Ah. So that's it... IEnumerator is only used when implementing GetEnumerator()?

Comment: @Istrebitel, basicly yes, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx :)